# How To enable automatically MultiPolygonField and PointField in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, geodjango

I am newbie on geodjango, is there any method or way to create MultiPolygonField and PointField in django admin automatically.

my model is as follows :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis import admin
# Create your models here.
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Country Name', max_length=200)
    lon = models.FloatField()
    lat = models.FloatField()
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField(default='SRID=3857;POINT(0.0 0.0)')
    geometry = models.PointField(srid=4326,default='SRID=3857;POINT(0.0 0.0)')
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

admin.site.register(Country,admin.GeoModelAdmin)
```

Please help me.

Comment: I guess there is a copy/paste error in your script here: `mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField(default='SRID=3857;POINT(0.0 0.0)')` since you want to create a polygon. I have never tried two geometries in the same model. Did you find an solution? If yes, i'm interested. If not, i would consider helping you with it. Cheers.